# texstudio preference change not saved

Tags: texstudio

As of lately I've become quite annoyed with Texstudio. The reason for this is that the bibliography (F11) is no longer working for me. As it turns out, somehow this hotkey is *also* assigned to the view/fullscreen mode action, which apparently means that F11 now does neither. I fixed this by removing the hotkey entry for 'fullscreen', but the issue returns every time I restart Texstudio. Apparently this setting isn't being saved. Oddly enough, my user-defined commands *are* being saved. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Which version/OS of TeXstudio are you using ?

Comment: Maybe you should check the permissions on your texstudio.ini. Under Kubuntu it would be located in ~/.config/. Maybe it got accidentially write protected.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. I am using Windows 7 professional, unfortunately I can't check the Texstudio version right now as I am not at home, will add it later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug related to OS-dependent shortcut settings. Will be fixed in the next release.

As a workaround, you may assign any other shortcut to 'fullscreen', e.g. 'Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F11'.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! It no longer resets when TeXstudio is restarted either.